# Strange Laravel/VALET node_modules error on scratch setup MacOS Sierra

Tags: laravel, composer-php, macos-sierra, iterm2, laravel-valet

I have been experiencing with this issue, since i install composer perfectly and then requiring `laravel/valet` globally.

When I hit

```
'valet' on iterm/zsh
```

what returns is as below.

```
module.js:540
   throw err;
   ^
Error: Cannot find module './node_modules/coffee-script'
   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
   at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
   at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
   at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/valet. /node_modules/express.io/switch.js:5:5)
   at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
   at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
```

I also tried to:

```
npm i coffee-script
npm i coffeescript
```

nothing works.

I don't know what code I should I share with you.

Comment: Try running `npm i coffee-script` (notice the typo fix)

Comment: @JasonK made a typo there, thx for letting me know.

Comment: still not working,

Comment: Can you confirm that the module is actually installed? Check for errors during installation and check if the `node_modules/coffee-script` folder exists.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @JasonK hey,

Under `/Users/kaankucuk/System/vendor/laravel` and `/Users/kaankucuk/System/vendor/laravel/valet` ı have two node_modules folder with both coffeescript and coffee-script, they both have package-lock.json

I think i am missing something at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the path on error thrown by npm and deleted node_modules folder.

Afterwards valet install worked.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you installed the node modules within the folder of the composer package `laravel/valet`. You should run the `npm i coffee-script` command from the [root directory](https://laravel.com/docs/master/structure#the-root-directory) of your Laravel project. Another option is to run `npm i coffee-script -g` to install coffeescript as a global dependency.